# Install both libmemcached10 and libmemcached6 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python, php

Just wondering if someone can help me here, I'm still quite new to Ubuntu an Linux in general and seem to be having a problem with two packages:

libmemcached10 is required for php5-memcached
but
libmemcached6 is required for python-pylibmc

See info below-

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmemcached10
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libmemcached6 python-pylibmc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libmemcached10 php5-memcached
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If I install either one it will break the other, I have read after a quick google search you can install them side-by-side but I'm not 100% sure how and if I should do this?

Any help/advice would be appreciated, Thanks
(If you need more information please ask)

Comment: Unless you need libmemcached6, feel free to remove it if it's unneeded by another package

Comment: Thats the problem I have if I remove libmemcached6 I cannot install python-pylibmc which I need, is it possible to install python-pylibmc with libmemcached10?, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hold the package `libmemcached6` by running,

```
sudo apt-mark hold libmemcached6
```

Then install `libmemcached10` package by running,

```
sudo apt-get install libmemcached10
```